# I can't see my web site with www

Tags: web

I uploaded a web site to my server.

When I go to `http://overflod.mx/`, I can see the page:

[image: overflod.mx screen shot]

but when I visit `http://www.overflod.mx/` 
(NOTE: "www" added), I can´t see it!

[image: www.overflod.mx screen shot]

Could somebody tell me what could I do to solve the problem? Do I need to redirect the web site or what?

Comment: These are the same URL's ... ?? Typo?  Which one doesn't work??

Comment: @Dreamwalker I think StackJon meant to say "overflod.mx" the first time, so it maches his screenshot. In any case, "www.overflod.mx" and "overflod.mx" are technically different zones, so you will indeed need to redirect "www.overflod.mx" to "overflod.mx" to get the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: @Max ... this redirect should happen on the server, set by the host? right?

Comment: This redirect should happen on the server, correct. It should be a 301 (permanent) redirect from "www.overflod.mx" to "overflod.mx".

Comment: Thank you @MaximillianLaumeister I'm gonna do it!

Comment: clarified question, was pretty much fine to begin with. also note, the author has gotten the answer he needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check your cpanel back. You have to see whether the "www" has been added to your cname on your dns. If it does, try contacting your domain provider.Try reading:

[Wordpress support on www.subdomain.other.com](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wwwsubdomaindomaincom-not-working)

[Managing DNS Records/Cname](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727018.aspx)

I hope it helps.

All the best,
Muhaimin